# Angular JS and getting values from a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these functions that do calculations of values from input fields using ng-model.

```
 $scope.EmployeeCompetenceObs = function () {
      return $scope.user.percentEmployeesCompetentAfterTraining - $scope.user.percentEmployeesCompetentBeforeTraining;
  }
```

and what I am trying to do is get the value from that function and use it in another function:

```
$scope.EmployeeCompetenceAtt = function () {
      return EmployeeCompetenceObs() - $scope.user.adjustmentFactorsEmployeeCompetence;
  }
```

but when I call {{EmployeeCompetenceAtt()}} it comes up ad undefined...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return $scope.EmployeeCompetenceObs()...` and not `return EmployeeCompetenceObs()...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EmployeeCompetenceObs` is a function in the `$scope`, as you declared it, so you should invoke it by doing:

```
$scope.EmployeeCompetenceObs()
```

You omitted that part in your invocation and that is most likely the cause of the error.